# Calling GCP HTTPS function with cURL without any "dependencies"

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, curl, https, cloud

Edited based on "Guillaume Blaquiere" answer:

I have a GCP(Google Cloud Platform) HTTPS function, I need to research the difference between "Cloud Functions", "Cloud Run" and "App Engine".
[And I'll look into this tonight, thank you Guillaume Blaquiere](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1)

I have a RaspberryPi computer as a client which calls the HTTPS function.

I want to use an API-Key or Private-Key to authenticate instead of a bearer token or something similar. That way it can be set up once and used forever.
I accept the security risk because in my case if something happens, I will just set it up again. (with a new key)

I need a "prebaked" cURL command like this: (which dose work, for a short period of time)

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGc-MY-BEARER-TOKEN-3Uw3kURBQ" https://<region>-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/myfunction
```

This is how the command is normally called: (which I cant use)

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" https://<region>-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/myfunction
```

I cant use any variables and I cant set anything up on the RaspberryPi,
I need one cURL command.
Is this possible?

Comment: Google does not provide long-lived authorization. Therefore you must implement your own authentication/authorization system such as using a secret key that only your app and service know. However, that means anyone can invoke your function instance as it is not protected by the Google IAP. Your code can reject unauthorized requests but you will pay for that invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not an encryption problem, but an authentication problem.

> How to be sure that is YOUR Raspberry that call your Cloud Function and not something else?

If you use native feature of Cloud Functions, you need a short lived token (and therefore your raspberry need an internet connection to generate a new one every hours). It's a security best practice. Like that, if the token is stolen, it can be used only 1 hour never more before a new steal.

The problem with long lived token (like API Keys) is that, in case of thief, it can be used for days, months, years!!

But, in some case, you do not have other option. I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1) on that, based on ESPv2, but if you use [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway), the mechanism is very similar (it's a managed ESPv2 service!)